# java tokenize strings read from a text file

Tags: java, arraylist, tokenize

I have this program that reads a text file from my computer. the text file is a list of titles. Im trying to figure out how to tokenize what is returned so that I get the full name instead of a piece. All the examples I am able to find involve regular arrays and Im using an arraylist. I need to be able to read each string back into my arraylist and cut it off where the & are.

The Text file looks like this:

Star Wars& DVD&

Lord of the Rings&  DVD&

Resident Evil& DVD&

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        File f = new File("file.txt");
        try {
            ArrayList<String> lines = get_arraylist_from_file(f);
            for (int x = 0; x < lines.size(); x++) {
                System.out.println(lines.get(x));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("done");

    }

    public static ArrayList<String> get_arraylist_from_file(File f)
            throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner s;
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        s = new Scanner(f);
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            list.add(s.next());
        }
        s.close();
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: Is it 1 title per line?

Comment: Please post exact how the input file looks. Are each name on a separate line?

Comment: Sorry, I have posted an example of how the data looks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     public static ArrayList<String> get_arraylist_from_file(File f) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scanner;
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        scanner = new Scanner(f);
        String s = scanner.nextLine();

        while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
        String[] tempList = s.split("&"); //This will give you this [title][ DVD]
        String title = tempList[0];
        String type = tempList[1].subString(1); //If you want the input at the place of DVD, with the space removed
        list.add(title);
        s = scanner.nextLine();
        }
        scanner.close();
        return list;
}
```

Comment: I have replaced my while statement but I am getting an error because the variable s already Scanner s. After replacing the variable nextLine and hasNextLine are giving me errors that they are undefined for the type string.

Comment: Yeah I didn't give you the whole code, thought you could edit it by your self. Since you apparently couldn't do this, I´ll fix it for you.

Comment: Thank you. That is what I basically came up with after renaming the scanner. My only problem now is that s.close(); is now saying that "method close() is undefined for the type String" Which im looking into now.

Comment: Sorry forgot to edit that, of course it's the scanner you shall close. scanner.close();

Comment: I tried changing that to scanner.close(); but I kept getting this error "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at testingStuff.Testing.get_arraylist_from_file(Testing.java:43)
 at testingStuff.Testing.main(Testing.java:23)"

Comment: I figured it out. The String type = tempList[1].substring(1); was causing it to error.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (s.hasNextLine()) {
    list.add(s.nextLine().replaceAll("&", ""));
}
```

removes the ampersands

Comment: I thought I needed those so that when I opened my file I was able to return the string starting from that character?

Comment: changed based on file descriptor.  You don't need to include & to return the string starting from &--it seems you can return the last word.